# Button change after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a button that I want to control a process. The process can be run/pause/stop.

```
<div>
    <button class="buttonAction" id="run"  onclick = "sendData()"   >Run</button>
    <button class="buttonAction" id="pause" onclick = "sendData1()" >Pause</button>

</div>
```

So the buttons are in the same position and what I want is when the the run button is clicked the pause button appears and visa versa.

```
  function sendData(){
   //some values
window.location.href = '${createLink(controller:'run', action:'run')}' + '?dbvalue=' + db +  '&fsvalue=' + fs;
document.getElementById("run").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("pause").style.visibility="visible";

}
```

Whats happens is it appears for a second but then reverts back to run because of the page reload window.location.href which I am using to send values back to my controller.

Dos anyone know a way to fix this or a better way of implementing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Reloading the page is like erasing a whiteboard and starting over again. The next page is not going to remember the state of the JavaScript you run after it. Setting of the buttons needs to take place on the next page load. Ideally your serverside code should be setting the state of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
function sendData(){
 //your implementation

 $("#run").css("visibility","hidden");
 $("#pause").css("visibility","visible");
} 

 function sendData1(){
 //your implementation

 $("#pause").css("visibility","hidden");
 $("#run").css("visibility","visible");
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for future viewers if you accept the answer as correct so they don't have to red the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use cookies or sessions to keep the changes after a page reload.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on run, sendData function will be called in that run will be displayed and pause will not displayed, as I kept style.display="none" in the same way if we click on pause, run button will not display as we are using style.display="none"

```
function sendData(){
document.getElementById("run").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("pause").style.display="none";
}
function sendData1(){
document.getElementById("run").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("pause").style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the problem. A few of the answers didnt take into account that the page reloaded.
When the user clicked run I send this back to the controller

```
window.location.href = '${createLink(controller:'run', action:'run')}' + '?dbvalue=' + db+  '&buttonValue=' + "hideRun"
```

Then in the controller I took the hideRun and send it back to the page

```
 String button = params.buttonValue
 render view:'run.gsp', model:[button:button]
```

Then I had a a function that gets called on each page load

```
             window.onload = function()
```

Which checked the value of

```
        "${button}"
```

Then if it ssaid "hideRun" it would hide the urn button which would display the pause button.
And visa versa...